# Socket and postgreSQL connection problem while connecting spring boot application to postgreSQL in eclipse

Tags: postgresql, maven, spring-boot, jpa, jdbc

I am running a maven spring boot application which fetches data from postgreSQL. But I am getting such type of error when I run the project using the command

> mvn spring-boot:run

->

```
2019-05-29 14:37:03.750  WARN 18368 --- [           main] unknown.jul.logger                       : IOException occurred while connecting to mc:19745
```

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

```
2019-05-29 14:36:52.241 ERROR 18368 --- [           main] org.postgresql.Driver                    : Connection error:
```

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
```

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

```
2019-05-29 14:36:53.245 ERROR 18368 --- [           main] 
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
```

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
```

I have mentioned only the main errors.

The application.properties file is:

```
spring.main.banner.mode=/offlinekyc

# Oracle settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://mc:19745/post
spring.datasource.username=postgre
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=oms_owner
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
http.mappers.json-pretty-print=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

hibernate.discriminator.ignore_explicit_for_joined=false

# create and drop tables and sequences, loads import.sql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

# HikariCP settings
# spring.datasource.hikari.*

spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5

#hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
#hibernate.default_schema=oms_owner
#hibernate.show_sql=true
#hibernate.format_sql=true
#hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false

# Because detection is disabled you have to set correct dialect by hand.
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

Hibernate.properties file also have the same matter.
Here my post database is in mc:19745 server. I am little confused regarding localhost and server address.

Can anyone help in this matter?

Comment: you have multiple `spring.datasource.*` entries in your properties file

Comment: @Paizo Yes, I removed one entry, but still getting same type of error : IOException occurred while connecting to mc:19745

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Comment: Are you sure you have a PostgreSQL running on host `mc` port 19745?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, I checked the connections.